# OpenVPN server, executing openvpn with the config as argument produces no output

Tags: openvpn, arch-linux

I have the following OpenVPN server config, which when I try to give as argument produces no output and simply returns.

```
[root ~]# cat /etc/openvpn/server/myvpnserver.conf 
port 28191
proto tcp
dev tun0

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/vpn-rpi.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/vpn-rpi.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/dh.pem

server 192.168.1.50 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3

log-append /var/log/openvpn
status /tmp/vpn.status 10
```

And when I try to execute it, I get:

```
[root ~]# openvpn /etc/openvpn/server/myvpnserver.conf
[root ~]#
```

The return code from $? is 1.

This is Arch Linux on a Raspberry Pi, with OpenVPN as follows:

```
[root ~]# openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.5.3 [git:makepkg/ecaf88f8a4e75856+] armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jun 18 2021
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021, LZO 2.10
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2021 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines:
```

Why does it produce no output? What should I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: 98191 is not a valid port number.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks, I changed it to 28191 though, and I still get the exact same problem. Also updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the `log-append` config option is present, all log messages will go to that file, and not to the standard output, so you should check that file.

It might worth noting that `log-append` expects a filename, not a directory, which makes your config suspect. Did you really wanted to log into a *file* called `/var/log/openvpn`?